# Is a hash from a picture taken from a camera truly random?

Tags: python, random, random-seed

I'm currently taking a picture with a webcam, hashing (sha-512) the bytes output of that image. Is that a "true" random number generator? On the `ent` test, it performs badly. I suspect this is because it does not have any special characters, only letters and numbers. What hashing algorithm would be better suited for this than sha-512?
here's my code:

```
import cv2
import hashlib

webcam = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
check, frame = webcam.read()
framebytes = frame.tobytes()
hash = sha512(str(framebytes).encode('utf-8')).hexdigest()
```

(talking about `hash` here)
I'm currently using this inside a webserver (flask), so I'm not able to serve bytes (trying to make a random api, used as the seed)

Comment: Why do you need to build your own random number generator? Why not use any of the existing ones?

Comment: Since flipping a single input bit should flip roughly half the output bits in a way which can't be feasibly distinguished from chance, if it doesn't pass tests for randomness you are probably applying the test incorrectly. See [this question](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/76382/31720) from [cryptography.se].

Comment: @NicoHaase because I want to learn

Comment: might help to clarify what you mean by `sha-512`, I'm assuming this is the SHA2 hash with a 512 bit digest.  if that's the case, you get 512 bits back, which are commonly transformed into 128 ASCII characters giving a hexadecimal representation of those 512 bits.  if you want the raw bits, then you want to ask for them or transform this ASCII representation appropriately.  note that you should aim to get 512 / 8 = 64 bytes of output from each digest.

Comment: @SamMason Your assumption is correct. I have the option to get the digest in bytes, or hex, which should I choose? would bytes "lead to more entropy per byes"

Comment: I'd presume that picking bytes would be the right thing to do.  Note that adding some code would help a lot, I'm just making guesses based on your very incomplete description so far...

Comment: @SamMason I've edited the question, I hope it gives more context for you.

Comment: Be careful of unexpected consequences in complicated systems like this -- for example If 12 hours out of every day the lights were off and the picture was 100% black then this would be a very bad way to get a random number.

Comment: @Hogan presumably the camera's AGC would try and compensate which would actually tend to increase entropy, generally the cheaper the webcam the less control one has and the more likely this behavior will be.  that said, using `urandom` is almost always the right solution here!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really want to do this, then your code is mostly right.  Except:

- There's no point in converting from bytes to a string and back again
- Just request the digest directly, rather than a hex representation of them

For example:

```
from cv2 import VideoCapture
from hashlib import sha512

webcam = VideoCapture(0)
check, frame = webcam.read()

if not check:
  raise ValueError("Unable to read a frame")

digest = sha512(frame).digest()
```

That said, you'd be much better off using [`os.urandom`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.urandom), or a wrapper like [`SystemRandom`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.SystemRandom) and let your OS take care of things.  This service is trusted by programs like OpenSSL and should be more reliable than what you're trying to do.

If you really want to use a webcam, I'd suggest mixing the entropy into the system's while still using `urandom` to get out random values.  Note that, under Linux, you can write the hashed bytes from your webcam (or even the raw webcam data) into `/dev/random` to incorporate this in a cryptographically secure manner.

If you really want to do things yourself, I'd suggest having a look at the [Fortuna PRNG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fortuna_(PRNG)) for how larger systems treat entropy extraction and the attacks they try and defend against.